# LSTM advantages

Tags: machine-learning, lstm

Can someone briefly explain what does this (bold) mean:
LSTM is well-suited to classify, process and predict time series **given time lags of unknown size and duration between important events**.

Thank you

Comment: As LSTM is able to model long terms dependencies it may be better suited for such a scenario. As it can automatically learn these lags between important events. For more clarifications please share the source you are referring to

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-forecasting-with-deep-learning-and-attention-mechanism-2d001fc871fc                                                                                                               Hi, there's the article I am reading on. Thank You